# Rails render call won't display when called from helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, helper, partials

I have section of code that works when placed in the view, but fails to render when the code is moved to a helper. I know the code is executing because the server shows the render call, but there is no output to the browser.

This works (when placed in the view file)

```
<% vidList = "ylLzyHk54Z0", "ylLzyHk54Z0", "ylLzyHk54Z0", "ylLzyHk54Z0" %>
<% i=1 %>
<% vidList.each do |v| %>
  <%= render partial: 'loadvid', locals: {vidId: i.to_s, divId: "vid"+i.to_s, vidURL: v } %>
  <% i=i+1 %>
<% end %>
```

This does not.

```
module VidsHelper
  def loadvids(vidList)
    i=1
    vidList.each do |v|
      render partial: 'loadvid', locals: {vidId: i.to_s, divId: "vid"+i.to_s, vidURL: v }
      i=i+1
    end
  end
end
```

As I said, I know the method is being called because the server reports that `_loadvid.html.erb` was rendered 4 times. It is being called with

```
<% vidList = "ylLzyHk54Z0", "ylLzyHk54Z0", "ylLzyHk54Z0", "ylLzyHk54Z0" %>
<% loadvids vidList %>
```

When I view source in the browser absolutely nothing is being rendered.

Comment: Try <%= loadvids vidList %>

Comment: Already tried that. Just shows the vidlist array content and doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, any call within <% %> will not display. Calling the function within <%= %>, however, shows the output of the method, not the render output.  The only solution I can see is to capture the render output and then re-render it.  The current working code is this:

In the view:

```
  <%= render inline: loadvids(vidList) %>
```

In the helper:

```
def loadvids (vidList)
    i=1
    capture = []
    vidList.each do |v|
        capture.push render partial: "loadvid", locals: {vidId: i.to_s, divId: "vid"+i.to_s, vidURL: v }
        i=i+1
    end
    capture.join
end
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if this solution works for you.